# Polynomial-time algorithm for exact projection to polyhedral cone

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, convex-geometry, polyhedra, cones

Given $c \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, project $c$ to the [polyhedral cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone#Polyhedral_and_finitely_generated_cones) $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid A x \leq 0\}$. Is there an algorithm that outputs an *exact* solution to this problem in polynomial time?

One approach: For each subset $I \in \mathcal{P}([n])$ of constraints, project to $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid A_Ix = 0\}$. Over this finite set of candidates, take the one closest to $c$ that satisfies all constraints. Unfortunately, iterating over all subsets requires exponential time.

Paper 1 presents an algorithm for exact projection to a polyhedron (of which a polyhedral cone is a special case). However, it also requires exponential time:

> Theorem 2 suggests the following finite algorithm for finding the projection $P_C(x)$ for $x \not\in C$: Let $\Delta := \{I_1, I_2, \ldots, I_{2^n - 1}\}$ be the collection of all nonempty subsets of $N$ and let $m$ = 1. [...] In Step 2 of the algorithm at most $2^n−1$ systems
> are solved of at most $n$ equations.

Paper 2 presents an algorithm that seems to have nondeterministic steps and require exponential time:

> Step 3. Replace some of the columns of $WB_1$ with those of $A_1$ to get a matrix $V$, i.e. the $i$th column of $V$ is either $W\beta_i$ or $\alpha_i$ ($i=1, \ldots, t$). Assume this occurs to $i = i_1, \ldots, i_s$.
>
> Step 4. Compute $Q = (V, W B_2)^*_{D_2}$ and $y=Q'Wx$.
>
> Step 5. If the first $t$ components of $y$ are non-positive, go to Step 6; otherwise Step 3.

If necessary, it can be assumed that the polyhedral cone has the form $Bx = 0, x \geq 0$ (the intersection of a [linear subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace) and the nonnegative [orthant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthant)).

---

References:

1. [*Closed-form expressions for projectors onto polyhedral sets in Hilbert spaces*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00102). Krzysztof E. Rutkowski. SIAM Journal on Optimization. Volume 27, issue 3. 2017-04-19.
2. [*An exact algorithm for projection onto a polyhedral cone*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-842X.00018). Xiaomi Hu. Australian & New Zealand Journal of Statistics. Volume 40, issue 2. 2002-12-18.

Comment: Does it even make sense to talk about exact solutions in computer science to problems involving real numbers?

Comment: @SamHopkins Under the [arithmetic model of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Strongly_and_weakly_polynomial_time): *In this model of computation the basic arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and comparison) take a unit time step to perform, regardless of the sizes of the operands.*